# How can I make an application available not only in the UK store, but also in the US store

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have currently uploaded an application to the iTunes App Store & the application is online now, i've tried to download the application from an Apple ID registered within the US App Store & it gave me a message saying that "The app is only available in the UK App Store", although i did not specify on which Store I intend to release my app, which basically should make it available in all stores (according to what i read while submitting the application)

So any ideas how can i make it available on all App Stores or is impossible ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe you are just too fast trying to download the app? Try to wait for a while if the app has just been released?

Comment: i don't know :/, its been one week since the app is approved and on the app store

Comment: check your itunesconnect > manage apps > click on the problematic app > rights and pricing > click on the word "specific stores" > check if all stores are checked. Just edit and save as needed, set the effective date too for the changes.

Comment: Does it help? if it does, I can post it as an answer, then the question can be closed too instead of it remaining opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the territory in iTunes Connect during you submit your apps.
"The individual countries or territories where you want to sell your app. By default, your app is available in all countries the App Store currently supports."

Source: [Developer Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1)

Comment: does that mean that i cannot change it anymore :/ ?, do i have to re-submit my app over again ?
& Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You still can edit and update the app information include price and rights. :)
Please refer this link for further information:
[link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html)